# Installing Gearman from PPA on Ubuntu does not install libdrizzle?

Tags: ubuntu, gearman

I am attempting to install Gearman from the PPA. However, once installed running `gearmand --help` shows no libdrizzle options. My understanding is libdrizzle should be installed with Gearman.

I have removed the installed Gearman packages and then installed `libdrizzle-dev` and then tried to reinstall Gearman. However, this still does not work.

Is there something special I need to do to enable libdrizzle for Gearman via the PPA repository? My Google-fu is not returning any results on this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up just installing it a different way.

1. `apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`
2. `cd /tmp && wget https://launchpad.net/gearmand/1.2/1.1.2/+download/gearmand-1.1.2.tar.gz && tar xvfz gearmand-1.1.2.tar.gz && cd gearmand-1.1.2 && ./configure --prefix=/usr && make && make install`
3. `apt-get install gearman-job-server`

Vola, working like a charm. Can't believe this isn't documented anywhere...